# How do I break a non-straight line into even segments?

Tags: actionscript-3, geometry, polynomial-math, trigonometry, line-segment

I have a non-straight line defined by a series of x, y coordinate points.  I could draw a straight line on-screen directly between these points with no problem.  Unfortunately, I have to draw the line in segments of equal length.

Here is an example of how I need to break up a non-straight line with 3 points into an array of several equidistant points.  (ignore the final red dot, it is the result when a line does not divide evenly and is also the terminus)

[image: Here is an example of how I need to break up a non-straight line with 3 points into an array of several equidistant points]

Please notice the red line at the "joint".  Consider that I have a line A->B->C with the vectors AB and BC forming some angle.  Basically, the line bends at point B.

Segmenting a line between point A and B is no problem up to a point.  But when AB does not divide evenly by the segment length, I need to do something special.  I need to take that remaining length and consider it as one side of a triangle.  The constant segment length is another side of a triangle that connects with the BC segment (the red line above).  I need to know the length from point B to this intersection.  With this information, I can continue calculating line segments on BC.

[Here is the triangle I am trying to solve](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Triangle_with_notations_2.svg) (hereafter I will refer to the variables as they appear on this picture)
So far I have broken down the problem to using the law of cosines.  c<sup>2</sup> = a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> - 2ab * Cos(*y*)

The problem is that I already know c, it is the segment length.  I need to solve for a (I can calculate y).

I've gotten as far as writing a polynomial equation, but now I am stuck:
a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> - 2ab * Cos(*y*) - c<sup>2</sup> = 0

or Ax<sup>2</sup> + Bx + C (A = 1, B = -2b * Cos(*y*), C = b<sup>2</sup> - c<sup>2</sup>, x = a)

Is this even the right approach?  What do I do next?  I need to implement this in Actionscript.

EDIT: Duh, I would have to use the quadratic formula.  So I now get:

a = b * Cos(*y*) +/- SqrRoot(c<sup>2</sup> - b<sup>2</sup> * Sin(*y*)<sup>2</sup>)

Now how to put this into code...

Comment: if you add the url to the img,, I can edit it in your post.

Comment: I have upvoted your question,, you now have 13 rep,, so you can post the img.

Comment: Thank you!  I really appreciate it.  I think I have found the math solution (via Quadratic formula).  Now I just have to code it.  I have had to move on to another problem in the meantime, but when I get a change to code this, I will try to come back and post an answer.  In the meantime, I would welcome any suggestions.  Solving two equations and then testing which one is positive seems pretty intensive.  But it should only be necessary at joints, so hopefully the draw logic won't slow things down too much.

Comment: Do you want to draw polyline or curve through control points? For polyline, equal lengths on all segments are impossible without cutting corners (in general case.)

Comment: err, sorry, either I am confused or I confused you.  I will be drawing straight line segments, not curves, so I don't see where control points will come in.  I think the answer to your question is that I will cut the corner by inserting a 1-segment-length line near where the two lines AB and BC would otherwise connect, calculated using the above math.  The reason on insisting that the segments be the same length is because they will have an attached decoration of a set size.  For example, a weather cold front line segment will have a triangle (like on the news).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I solved this. B and C are the same as you defined them, I'm calling Point A the end of the last full segment on the first line. (the last point before the bend)  If you draw a circle with its center at A and a radius = your segment length, then where that circle intersects line BC is the endpoint (call it D) of a line from A that cuts your corner.  To find that point, I found a neat [helper function](http://keith-hair.net/blog/2008/08/05/line-to-circle-intersection-data/) It's not very long and for simplicity, I'm just pasting it here.

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Returns an Object with the following properties:
    enter           -Intersection Point entering the circle.
    exit            -Intersection Point exiting the circle.
    inside          -Boolean indicating if the points of the line are inside the circle.
    tangent     -Boolean indicating if line intersect at one point of the circle.
    intersects      -Boolean indicating if there is an intersection of the points and the circle.

If both "enter" and "exit" are null, or "intersects" == false, it indicates there is no intersection.

This is a customization of the intersectCircleLine Javascript function found here:

http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/index.htm

----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
function lineIntersectCircle(A : Point, B : Point, C : Point, r : Number = 1):Object {
    var result : Object = new Object ();
    result.inside = false;
    result.tangent = false;
    result.intersects = false;
    result.enter=null;
    result.exit=null;
    var a : Number = (B.x - A.x) * (B.x - A.x) + (B.y - A.y) * (B.y - A.y);
    var b : Number = 2 * ((B.x - A.x) * (A.x - C.x) +(B.y - A.y) * (A.y - C.y));
    var cc : Number = C.x * C.x + C.y * C.y + A.x * A.x + A.y * A.y - 2 * (C.x * A.x + C.y * A.y) - r * r;
    var deter : Number = b * b - 4 * a * cc;
    if (deter <= 0 ) {
        result.inside = false;
    } else {
        var e : Number = Math.sqrt (deter);
        var u1 : Number = ( - b + e ) / (2 * a );
        var u2 : Number = ( - b - e ) / (2 * a );
        if ((u1 < 0 || u1 > 1) && (u2 < 0 || u2 > 1)) {
            if ((u1 < 0 && u2 < 0) || (u1 > 1 && u2 > 1)) {
                result.inside = false;
            } else {
                result.inside = true;
            }
        } else {
            if (0 <= u2 && u2 <= 1) {
                result.enter=Point.interpolate (A, B, 1 - u2);
            }
            if (0 <= u1 && u1 <= 1) {
                result.exit=Point.interpolate (A, B, 1 - u1);
            }
            result.intersects = true;
            if (result.exit != null && result.enter != null && result.exit.equals (result.enter)) {
                result.tangent = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

It's a function that returns an object with several properties, so to implement in your code it's very simple. You need to pass it three points and a radius.  The first two points are just B and C as you defined them above, and Point A as I explained at the beginning.  The radius, again, is your segment length.

```
//create an object
var myObject:Object = lineIntersectCircle(pointB, pointC, pointA, segmentLength);
```

That's it! The coordinates of point D (see above) are: `(myObject.exit.x, myObject.exit.y)`

Comment: Mathworld has the background behind this calculation here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html

Comment: Cool, this should take less processing than the solution I came up with using the law of cosines.  Thank you!